# How to play already transfered music with 'Music' app?

Tags: usb, music, media-player

I just bought Galaxy S2. Its really cool, but I have one serious problem! I transfered few MP3 files using USB and copied those files to *usbStorage/*. When I open 'My files' app on S2, it does show those files.

When I open the 'Music' app, there aren't any clue of new files. Only the default music.

It there any way to somehow add that music to 'Music' app? Maybe I need to get other app to play music?

<sup>If relevant, I have a Samsung Galaxy S2 running Android 2.3.3 and my computer has Debian 6.0.2.</sup>

Comment: Is there a `/media/` folder or similar? I would try moving them there.

Comment: sometimes you have to scan from the music app. Otherwise, i would get an app like DoubleTwist, that and Google Music are really good at finding all the music on your phone, regardless of where it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is **NOT** to copy to the directory named `usbStorage`. Probably, just for Galaxy S2.

Create new directory named `Media` in `/` and move your music in it. Then, reboot (optional).

Answer (score 5):

Remount SD card or even restart will also work or just browse using any file manager type of apps and play using Music app...

Answer (score 3):

Just move your mp3 files to the Media folder on the phone and Music players will see them. You will also be able to assign the files to the contacts from your address book as personal ringtones.

Answer (score 1):

For syncing music to your device I use [Songbird](http://getsongbird.com/) and find it throughly good, and a great iTunes alternative.  I would suggest you run Songbird, then let it find all your music files, take the original files off your Samsung, and then sync Sonbird with the Galaxy device.  Good luck!

Builds can be found [here](http://wiki.songbirdnest.com/Developer/Articles/Builds/Contributed_Builds)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is install winamp on both your computer and your phone. It is a free software and app, so no purchase is necessary. This will do exactly what itunes does with i* devices.

Winamp will discover your phone on your computer and allow you to literally drag and drop your music files to your phone within winamp. It also imports all your songs from your itunes music folder, so it's a very simple process. It even updates the library if the itunes music folder is updated (songs are deleted or added).

Comment: Winamp will not run on Debian Linux.

Comment: Didn't see that part. I can't help you here then :/